# Domino Data Access response hangs for PATCH

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using the Domino Data Access (via RESTClient) to update docs in a database. I'm using PATCH and PUT.  In both cases (PATCH is a header override) I don't get a response back from the Domino server. RESTClient gives me a "processing data" and that's it. If I abort, I can see the replace or update has been done. So DDA is working, except I'm not getting a 200 or other response back. Default and Anonymous can create/edit (database is still in testing), and I've tried with and without the form and computewithform parameters. I'm not seeing anything in the server log.

Could someone give me a pointer of where to look? It seems that something is keeping the complete acknowledgment from being sent, but I don't know what that would be. Other testing, for GET, respond fine.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Turns out this was a problem with RESTClient, not DDA/DDS. Thanks to Fotios Hatzis who figured it out. I tried with a Chrome extension, and the response displays as exected.

Comment: Please put your comment into an answer and mark it "accepted" so that other people can find the answer.  Right now this question shows up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urns out this was a problem with RESTClient, not DDA/DDS. Thanks to Fotios Hatzis who figured it out. I tried with a Chrome extension, and the response displays as exected. –